# In CloudWatch Insights, how do I filter out log entries that don't have a parsed value?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

Suppose I have the following Insights query

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| parse @message 'status=*" as status
| display @timestamp, status, @message
```

Some log messages don't have a status. I'd like to filter those out. How do I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the `ispresent()` function: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/CWL_QuerySyntax.html

Like this:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| parse @message 'status=*" as status
| display @timestamp, status, @message
| filter ispresent(status)
```